# Realtime Face-tracking on Iphone

Tags: iphone, opencv, real-time, tracking, face-recognition

Does anybody know which,currently,is the best library for realizing a real time face-tracking solution for iPhone? I've done a research but I've found quite old articles about OpenCV portings. I would like to know if there is any specific,reliable,fast (and possibly free) AR solution for overlay in real time an image to the face in iPhone camera Video Stream (not simply a static image)

Any help (link,tutorial) would be great.

Thanks everybody!!

Elos

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`iOS 5` brings facial recognition as a native feature.

Basically you just have to configure an object to act as your the video output stream’s `delegate` (could be your controller, for example) and use a [CIDetector](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreImage/Reference/CIDetector_Ref/Reference/Reference.html) object to process this stream (which is a class available only in `iOS 5`).

This `CIDetector` object will look for the faces in each of your video's frame and return a [CIFaceFeature](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreImage/Reference/CIFaceFeature/Reference/Reference.html) object with several information about the faces found, such as the eyes and mounth position and also the `bounds` (the rectangle that the face was found inside).

---

You can check [this blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20130908115815/http://i.ndigo.com.br/2012/01/ios-facial-recognition/) for more implementation details:
https://web.archive.org/web/20130908115815/http://i.ndigo.com.br/2012/01/ios-facial-recognition/

Answer (score 5):

opencv is the best i think.

checkout this tutorial:
http://www.morethantechnical.com/2009/08/09/near-realtime-face-detection-on-the-iphone-w-opencv-port-wcodevideo/

Comment: this one builds on xcode out of the box! thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/beetlebugorg/PictureMe
a starting point... he's using opencv.