# Can I use iPhone face recognition in apps?

Tags: iphone, xcode, face-recognition

I want to develop an application for iPhone in xcode and integrate face recognition in the application to correspond to other application functions but I do not know how it is possible to use face recognition in my application. Any ideas?

Comment: do you know any third party library yet? openCV is a good try

Comment: possible duplicate of [Realtime Face-tracking on Iphone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323350/realtime-face-tracking-on-iphone)

Comment: See also [Looking for book or tutorials for implementing face detection in iphone sdk?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829972/looking-for-book-or-tutorials-for-implementing-face-detection-in-iphone-sdk)

Answer (score 2):

Check out this [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facial_recognition_system) page. It has a lot of references to algorithms, applications, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Check out OpenCV. Here's a blog post that should help get you started:

http://niw.at/articles/2009/03/14/using-opencv-on-iphone/en

Answer (score 1):

See the Apple published iOS sample code that implements face detection called 
[SquareCam](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SquareCam/Introduction/Intro.html). --

> Integrating with CoreImage's new CIFaceDetector to find faces in a real-time VideoDataOutput, as well as in a captured still image. Found faces are indicated with a red square.